# Site blinks after upgrade from Firefox 17 to Firefox 18

Tags: html, css, firefox, web-deployment

I have a website with background pictures, set by css. Earlier in Firefox 17 when I press submit button and page reloads it looked like only a part of the page was replaced and all background/menus etc are in place.
Now I have an issue that when I submit a form first all page becomes white and after it all page is drawn from skratch.
Do you have any ideas what can be changed in Firefox and is it possible to avoid it somehow?
P.S. I am not sure, can I give a link to website, or it will be treated as a spam.
Thanks.

Comment: i have this problem recently, i had it on firefox 17 too from around 1 month ago, it updated to firefox 18 and it didn't happen yet, exactly when i submit forms, but random websites, and random times, happens to some sites more often i would like to hear an answer too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox really enjoys one of the fastest reloads around. But keep in mind this is a browser issue, so what seems fast in Firefox will not look so fast in other browsers like Safari and Opera.

So the only think you can really do is to get your layout loaded as fast as you can possible ensure. And to do this, I would suggest:

1. Ensure that none or almost none javascript is running before your styles are displayed.
2. Ensure that your request is being properly managed at server-side. Take a good look into database queries and make sure your server blaze pages requests away in nearly 0ms.
3. Look out for presence of CSS functions in your stylesheets, as they may get CPU into proccess before displaying anything.
4. Last, but not least, try not to download too much in between pages. Any extensive KB downloads will drop your chances to perform the *'still effect'* when switching pages.

I think this is all you can do. :)

PS: Off course, double check your browser cache's configurations.

Comment: also maybe its an add-on bug, because it happened a lot to me on very websites not just one

Comment: It was solved when I removed a new-year ligths javascript code. Interesting, that it was ok before the upgrade and was much better in Chrome than in new FF. But because holidays are over, is is not a big issue to remove them. Thanks, Alvaro!